# Docker containers linked but mysql cannot be connected to

Tags: php, mysql, docker, nginx, dockerfile

I am quite new to docker and have been battling two days to get my system going. My compose file creates nginx, php-fpm, mysql and phpmyadmin containers. I can ping all containers from each other. But when I try installing anything from my mounted public_html volume into the database (like installing an app that needs to create tables in database), the app simply cannot connect to the database. I have made sure over and over credentials are correct. For the life of me I don't know where I'm going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I include my compose file below:

```
version: '3'
services:   
www:
container_name: site1-www
image: nginx:1.13.7-alpine
expose:
  - "80"
ports: 
  - 8001:80
networks:
  datacentre:
    aliases:
      - site1www  
env_file:
  - ".env"
environment:
  - NGINX_HOST=localhost
volumes:
  - /mnt/www/site1.test/public_html:/usr/share/nginx/html/
  - 
/mnt/www/site1.test/conf/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
depends_on:
  - db
links
  - db

phpfpm:
build: ./phpfpm
container_name: site1-phpfpm
networks:
  datacentre:
    aliases:
      - site1php
volumes:
  - /mnt/www/site1.test/public_html:/usr/share/nginx/html
  - /mnt/www/site1.test/conf/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
depends_on:
  - db
links
  - db

db:
container_name: site1-db
image: mariadb:10.3.2
ports:
  - 3400:3306  
env_file:
  - ".env"
environment:
  - MYSQL_DATABASE=test1db
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
  - MYSQL_USER=test1user
  - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
networks:
  datacentre:
    aliases:
      - site1db
volumes:
  - /mnt/dbdata:/var/lib/mysql

dbadmin:
image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
container_name: site1-dbadmin
ports:
  - 8000:80
networks:
  datacentre:
    aliases:
      - site1dbadmin
environment:
  - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
  - PMA_HOST=mysql
depends_on:
  - db
links
  - db

networks:
  datacentre:
    external:
      name: datacentre_net
```

Comment: please check if your link configuration is `links` or `links:`

Comment: most likely your 'app' isn't connecting on port 3400?

Comment: @Forbs port 3306 on the docker network

Comment: links are not required to access services on a user defined network

Answer (score 0):

The compose setup looks a bit complex for a first shot. Remove all the names and aliases and use service names for connections. Then build from there.

For the `www` service, nginx should configure `phpfpm:9000`  as the FastCGI worker.

Your PHP application and phpMyAdmin should be configured to connect to `db:3306`

```
version: '3'

services:   
  www:
    image: nginx:1.13.7-alpine
    ports: 
      - 8001:80
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    environment:
      - NGINX_HOST=localhost
    volumes:
      - /mnt/www/site1.test/public_html:/usr/share/nginx/html/
      - /mnt/www/site1.test/conf/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - phpfpm

  phpfpm:
    build: ./phpfpm
    volumes:
      - /mnt/www/site1.test/public_html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /mnt/www/site1.test/conf/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mariadb:10.3.2
    ports:
      - 3400:3306  
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test1db
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_USER=test1user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - /mnt/dbdata:/var/lib/mysql

  dbadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      - PMA_HOST=db
    depends_on:
      - db
```

`links` are not required to access services on a user defined network.